# spark streaming can't start multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, spark-streaming

I use spark streaming to receive Kafka's data like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaStreamExample")
  .setSparkHome("/home/kufu/spark/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6")
  .setExecutorEnv("spark.executor.extraClassPath","target/scala-2.11/sparkstreamexamples_2.11-1.0.jar")

val threadNum = 3

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))
val topicMap = Map(consumeTopic -> 1)

val dataRDDs:IndexedSeq[InputDStream[(String, String)]] = approachType match {
  case KafkaStreamJob.ReceiverBasedApproach =>
    (1 to threadNum).map(_=>
      KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkOrBrokers, "testKafkaGroupId", topicMap))
  case KafkaStreamJob.DirectApproach =>
    (1 to threadNum).map(_=>
      KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
        ssc, Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> zkOrBrokers),
      Set[String](consumeTopic)))
}

//dataRDDs.foreach(_.foreachRDD(genProcessing(approachType)))
val dataRDD = ssc.union(dataRDDs)
dataRDD.foreachRDD(genProcessing(approachType))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

the genProcessing generates a process to deal with the data, which will takes 5s(sleep 5s). Code are like this:

```
def eachRDDProcessing(rdd:RDD[(String, String)]):Unit = {
  if(count>max) throw new Exception("Stop here")
  println("--------- num: "+count+" ---------")

  val batchNum = count
  val curTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  Thread.sleep(5000)

  val family = approachType match{
    case KafkaStreamJob.DirectApproach => KafkaStreamJob.DirectFamily
    case KafkaStreamJob.ReceiverBasedApproach => KafkaStreamJob.NormalFamily
  }

  val families = KafkaStreamJob.DirectFamily :: KafkaStreamJob.NormalFamily :: Nil

  val time = System.currentTimeMillis().toString

  val messageCount = rdd.count()

  rdd.foreach(tuple => {
    val hBaseConn = new HBaseConnection(KafkaStreamJob.rawDataTable,
      KafkaStreamJob.zookeeper, families)
    hBaseConn.openOrCreateTable()
    val puts = new java.util.ArrayList[Put]()
    val strs = tuple._2.split(":")
    val row = strs(1) + ":" + strs(0) + ":" + time
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row))
    put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(KafkaStreamJob.tableQualifier),
      Bytes.toBytes("batch " + batchNum.toString + ":" + strs(1)))
    puts.add(put)
    hBaseConn.puts(puts)
    hBaseConn.close()
  })

  count+=1
  println("--------- add "+messageCount+" messages ---------")
}
eachRDDProcessing
```

but the spark streaming doesn't start multi-thread.Tasks were processed one by one, and each task took around 5s. My machine has 8 cores, and the spark run on one node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't spark streaming will start threads especially on driver. The point is if you have multiple nodes, your genProcessing will run on different nodes.

Further, if you call rdd.foreachPartition(...), suppose it should get better parallelism